# Получить первую строку из каждой группы ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

У меня есть таблица `[ChartData]`

```
Id      Time                     Open   Close   High    Low  Volume IdPair
1001    2017-05-25 14:59:00.000  7624   7361    7403    56   92     565
1002    2017-05-12 13:21:09.000  9388   719     8089    68   80     142
1003    2017-04-10 17:50:44.000  4084   17      4154    88   53     730
1005    2017-05-12 15:40:14.000  5621   2644    8889    72   28     923
1006    2017-02-28 15:05:40.000  2158   7356    6058    48   51     784
1007    2017-06-01 13:12:38.000  4034   2239    4092    48   94     587
```

И я группирую по временом интервале

```
GROUP BY
DATEPART(YEAR, Time),
DATEPART(MONTH, Time),
DATEPART(DAY, Time),
DATEPART(HOUR, Time),
(DATEPART(MINUTE, Time) / @Interval)
```

Как мне получить Open, где Time есть минимальный и Sum(Volume) для  каждой группы??

Comment: *Как мне получить Open, где Time есть минимальный* `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_by_expression ORDER BY Time ASC)` в подзапросе, и выбрать, где единица.

Comment: Надо не выбирать где единица, а сделать `SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES`. Это примерно тоже самое, но без подзапросов